# How to convert to ascii using node.js

Tags: node.js, ascii

I am trying to convert length message to ascii.
My length message is like

```
var ll = "0170";
```

In node js , is there some kind of function which converts into ascii?
Please help?

Comment: you want to convert the length of ll into ascii ? What do you want as output, a char ? an int ?

Comment: i want output as int. is that possible to convert 0170 to ascii?  not length

Comment: an ascii code is for a char, and a single char; not a string

Comment: i made an answer giving you the ascii code for each character of the string

Comment: does it works ?

Comment: call me crazy, but could it be that the OP actually just wants to have the character with the ASCII code 170?

Comment: @dulguuntur please edit the tags, this question has nothing to do with Node.js in particular, it's a JavaScript question

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple function(ES6) which converts a string into ASCII characters using **charCodeAt()**

```js
const toAscii = (string) => string.split('').map(char=>char.charCodeAt(0)).join(" ")

console.log(toAscii("Hello, World"))
```

**Output:**

-> `72 101 108 108 111 44 32 87 111 114 108 100`

You could create a prototype function aswell. There are many solutions :)

Answer (score 2):

you can't have an ascii code for a whole string.

An ascii code is an integer value for a character, not a string. Then for your string `"0170"` you will get 4 ascii codes

you can display these ascii codes like this

```
var str = "0170";

for (var i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++) {
    console.log(str[i].charCodeAt());
}

Ouput : 48 49 55 48
```

Answer (score 0):

use **charCodeAt()** function to covert asscii format.

```
var ll = "0170";
function ascii (a) { return a.charCodeAt(); }
console.log(ascii(ll[0]),ascii(ll[1]), ascii(ll[2]), ascii(ll[3]) )
```

**result:**

```
48 49 55 48
```

Comment: you only get the ascii code for the first character of the string doing it. The question is not totally clear but i don't think it's what he wants

Answer (score 0):

It is straightforward in javascript you can use the code below but you need to handle failure cases based on your requirements else you can use the npm package which provides [ascii-text-converter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ascii-text-converter) with all error handling.

```
function AsciiToText(ascii: string) {
  const asciiArray = ascii
    .split(" ")
    .map((code) => parseInt(code.trim(), 10))
    .filter((item) => !isNaN(item));

  const sentence = asciiArray
    .map((asciiValue) => String.fromCharCode(asciiValue))
    .join("");

  return sentence;
}
```